# Undo Local Changes to a File

Tags: github-for-mac

I made some changes to a local file in my Github repository.  How do I undo those changes, discarding them completely?

I would like a solution entirely in Github for Mac, avoiding the command line if possible (several similar questions and answers I've found here focus on command line solutions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Github for Mac,

1. Click the Changes tab at the left
2. Select the file
3. In the Repository menu bar item, select ``Discard Changes to Selected Files \ldots"
4. You'll be prompted to confirm the discard